# Auto-Close Brackets not Working in Jupyterlab shared remote server

Tags: python, jupyter-lab

Settings --> 'Auto Close Brackets' is checked, however when I type '(', '[', etc., brackets do not auto-close.

jupyterlab version == 3.4.4 (installed via anaconda)

Server o/s: RHEL 7.9 (Maipo)

Is anyone else experiencing this? It was allegedly fixed back in version 3.1.* via https://github.com/jupyterlab/jupyterlab/pull/12508, but of course I still have the issue.

[image: Problem Summary Snip]

Comment: I fixed this using generate-config command and updating the config file.